# What is the difference between SetBounds and SetBoundsCore

Tags: c#, winforms

In WinForms you can set the bounds of a control using `SetBounds`, or if you have created a user control, you can override `SetBoundsCore`. I was wondering, does they both do the same or are there any differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `SetBounds` is not virtual, so if you need to run some extra code when the bounds is set, your only options is to override `SetBoundsCore`.

`SetBounds` does some parameter validation, and contains the logic with regards to calling into `SetBoundsCore` with the correct size based on the `BoundsSpecified` parameter. It also makes sure not to call `SetBoundsCore` unless the size actually changes.

In other words, `SetBoundsCore` is the meat of the implementation, while `SetBounds` is the public entry point which contain validation and some other housekeeping logic.

Answer (score 3):

[SetBounds()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setbounds.aspx) is a `public` method that changes the location and size of a control. It calls the `protected virtual` [SetBoundsCore()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setboundscore.aspx) method under the hood.

It means that if you override `SetBoundsCore()`, you can change its algorithm (e.g. add location and size restrictions), and these changes will apply even if some code other than your own calls `SetBounds()`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the user calls `SetBounds` which forwards to `SetBoundsCore` to implement the actual behavior. `SetBoundsCore` should never be called by your code.