# Smooth resize for Windows Form

Tags: winforms, optimization, resize

I am recreating resize functionality for a Form with FixedSingle FormBorderStyle using the following methods to update the size/position:

```
private void resizeBottom()
{
    this.SuspendLayout();
    this.SetBoundsCore(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, this.Width, Cursor.Position.Y - this.Location.Y, BoundsSpecified.Size);
}

…(other resize helpers)...

protected override void SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height, BoundsSpecified specified)
{
    base.SetBoundsCore(x, y, width, height, specified);
    this.ResumeLayout();
}
```

However, when I attempt to resize the window I get a lot of artefacts, particularly if I resize at just the right speed, it looks like the window is being ’smeared’ across the screen. I have tried enabling double buffering but it doesn’t seem to make a difference.

Comment: Where are you calling `resizeBottom`? Is it called once or as an animation? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8776905/880990

Comment: I'm calling it in my MouseMoved event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some tests and got a result very similar to what happens when you resize the form the regular way (by clicking and dragging a window edge with the mouse) with this code:

```
private void resizeBottom()
{
    SetBounds(Location.X, Location.Y, Width, Cursor.Position.Y + 30 - Location.Y);
}

protected override void SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height,
                                      BoundsSpecified specified)
{
    base.SetBoundsCore(x, y, width, height, specified);
    Update();
}
```

`Update()` makes the form to redraw instantly.

Note: I used `Cursor.Position.Y + 30`, otherwise I can only make the form smaller, since the mouse leaves the window if I move down.

Comment: This works great, the Update() call was what improved things drastically.